What is the physical meaning of the average value of the long product of spin operators
For the quantum one-dimensional XYZ Heisenberg model with $N$ spins $1/2$, consider the following average values of the products of successive operators $\hat{\sigma}^x$ in the ground state
$$
C_j(n) = \langle \prod_{l=0}^n\hat{\sigma}^x_{j+l}\rangle.
$$
Do such averages have any specific physical meaning?
I think that when increasing $N$ to $\infty$, the value of $C_1(N-1)$ may tend to some non-zero value or may decrease exponentially, like $\sim\exp(-aN)$, with some constant $a$. Something similar is probably true for the quantities $C(n) = \lim_{N\to\infty}C_{[\alpha N]}(n)$, where $\alpha$ is a constant, $0<\alpha<1$ , when increasing $n$. So, is it possible that the limit values are non-zero, and what meaning do they have if so?
The answer to this question is clear in cases where the ground state has the form of a product and describes a system of non-entangled particles, so I want to know the answer for cases where the ground state describes a system of entangled particles.

If all the spins are aligned, will the average value of that be zero? What value will it tend to?

@naturallyInconsistent In a state in which all spins are oriented in the direction of the $x$ axis, all $C_j(n)$ are equal to $1$, but when the alignment direction is different, the limit values are zero. So what? The ground state of the general XYZ model corresponds to different phases depending on the parameters $J^\alpha_j$, $h^\alpha_j$. Can you tell how $C_j(n)$ behaves for $n\gg 1$ in the well-studied case of a spatially homogeneous XXZ model without an external field in an ordered antiferromagnetic phase, when $J^z>J^x=J^y>0$ , and in the critical phase, when $|J^z|<J^x=J^y$?
